# Prevent child border radius from affecting parent in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari the border of the  element is unaffected by the border-radius of it's child  which is what I want. In IE 11 and Edge however, the border-radius of the  causes the  element to act as if it has a border radius. How can I fix this?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

td {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[CodePan](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpxLLz)

Comment: What is the point to set border radius to the <td> element if you don't have border for it?

Comment: The point of the inner border radius is to affect a box-shadow. The codepen just has a minimum working example demonstrating the border problem. It does not include all the extra css that I have in my real use case including the box-shadow.

Comment: Changing the `tr`'s display to `block` fixes it, but I don't know if this will have adverse affects with your table layout. Seems to be an Edge bug - very odd behavior

Comment: Yeah @zgood changing to display: block completely borks my layout :(

Comment: td{text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:20px;}*{box-sizing:border-box}